# Set theory, is this question too ambiguously worded to answer? $|A \cap B \cap C|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure about this question as the way that it's worded is tricky.

---

Question -

> A company who wanted to develop its internet presence had 27 of its employees each
>   investigate at least one of AOL, Demon, and BT. If 14 investigated AOL, 16 investigated
>   BT, and 8 investigated Demon, while 1 investigated AOL and Demon, 5 investigated
>   AOL and 5 investigated BT and Demon, how many investigated all three?
>
> A company had 27 of its employees each investigate at least one of A, D, and
>   B. If 14 investigated A, 16 investigated B, and 8 investigated D, while 1
>   investigated A and D, 5 investigated A and 5 investigated B and D, how many
>   investigated all three?

So I'm trying to pull out the relevent information from this and I have

27 of its employees (this is the total amount involved in this question)

- 14 investigated A
- 16 investigated B
- and 8 investigated D

while

1 investigated A and D
5 investigated A
5 investigated B and D

#### how many investigated all three?

I'm getting confused as the information seems to be really awkward, why would
they word it in such a way that they mention `14 investigated A`, then go onto
say that `5 investigated A`, it seems that it should be worded `19
investigated A`?

I appreciate that the value I'm trying to get is the centre point of the venn
diagram, where all sets overlap.

Also that the formula for such is

$$ |M \cup B \cup D  | = |M| + |B| + |D| - |M \cap B| - |M \cap D| - |B \cap D| + |M \cap B \cap D| $$

With the final $ |M \cap B \cap D| $ being what I'm trying to reach in order to
answer the question of how many investigated all three.

But I'm really stuck with where to go on it

cheers

Comment: " 14 investigated A, then go onto say that 5 investigated A,"  That's probably a typo.  If 14 investigated then at least 5 investigated so you don't need to add them

Comment: I think its supposed to be "5 investigated A and B".

Comment: @fleablood that would make complete sense actually stepping back and looking at the whole as $A \cap D$ and $B \cap D$ have been given, and having $A \cap B$ would make it pretty easy to solve I *think...*. I'll have a look at that, how annoying that I spent so long thinking I was missing something `>.<` (Which I guess I was in a way ha)

Answer (score 1):

> A company had 27 of its employees each investigate at least one of A, D, and B. If 14 investigated A, 16 investigated B, and 8 investigated D, while 1 investigated A and D, 5 investigated A and B, 5 investigated B and D, how many investigated all three?

You have all values you need right there.   Just rearrange your equation so what you want to find is on the left and what you know is on the right.

$$\lvert A \cap B \cap D \rvert = \lvert A \cup B \cup D \rvert - \lvert A\rvert - \lvert B\rvert - \lvert D\rvert + \lvert A \cap B\rvert + \lvert A \cap D\rvert + \lvert B \cap D\rvert$$

Comment: In your quote you've added the $B$ to $5 \text{ investigated } A \cap B$, in the OP there was only A there